# How to create a snk for .NETCore in Linux for Strong Named Assemblies

Tags: .net-core, rider

I write .NETCore servers using CentOS 7 using the JetBrains Rider IDE.

I need to create a bunch of **strong named assemblies** (library projects) for .NETCore 2.0. I know that on Windows I can use the `sn.exe` tool to create the `snk` key files. Can anybody elaborate a bit how to do this on a CentOS machine?

I have found a mono binary also called `sn` ([see man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sn)) which seems to be the `sn.exe` equivilent but it seems to be pretty old (2003 / 2004) and I am not sure, if it is the tool one should use **TODAY**.

Also I need to **sign** some DLLs with an **official (from a commerial vendor) `code signing certificate`**. I do NOT understand the relation between a `snk` file and the certificate I got (it has a `p12` extension).

From researching a little bit, I read, that in my `.csproj` file I need to add the following tags to advice `MSBUILD` to create strong named assemblies:

```
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>MyKey.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
<SignAssembly>True</SignAssembly>
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain how to (on **CentOS 7 targeting .NetCore 2.0**):

1. Create strong named assemblies
2. Sign an assembly with an existing commercial certificate

Please note that I am NOT using VisualStudio (where you have UI tools)!

Answer (score 2):

`sn -k sgKey.snk`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-create-a-public-private-key-pair

It works on Linux. Mono should be installed. Tried with .Net Core 2.2

---

Some useful command:

Create a key pair:  `sn –k private.snk`

Extract public key:     `sn –p private.snk public.snk`

View public key and public key token:   `sn –tp public.snk`

View public key and public key token of assembly:   `sn –Tp assembly.dll`

Extract public key from assembly:   `sn –e assembly.dll public.snk`

Verify if assembly is signed and with what key:     `sn –vf assembly.dll`

Show list of assemblies on machine registered for verification skipping: `sn –Vl`

Register assemblies for verification skipping:  `sn –Vr * (must elevate)`

Resign an assembly with the key pair:   `sn –Ra assembly.dll private.snk`